# Knockout not calculating observable inside attr binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to use `jquery.validate with knockout`. I have a list of objects, inside `foreach` binding,

*I have this code:*

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: fee">
     <tr>
          <td>
              <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: fee, attr: {name : 'srv'+$index()}" data-val="true" data-val-number="error msg" data-val-regex="err msg" data-val-regex-pattern="\d+(\.\d{1,2})?" data-val-required="required"/>

              <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-bind="attr : { 'data-valmsg-for': 'srv'+$index()}" />
         </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

The input name is correctly calculated, `eg. srv0, srv1` and so forth
while the name of validation span remains `srv+$index()`.

How to fix it?

Comment: It _might_ be because you've self closed the span tag - the starting and end tags of spans are mandatory.  Try changing it to have a `</span>`.  Might not solve the problem, but your code will be better for it anyway.

Comment: Hmm, [nope it's not that](http://jsfiddle.net/q21umv9z/).  You may need to post more code to clarify what's happening.

Comment: @JamesThorpe that's really all the code, just a data-bind="foreach: fees" in the tbody

Comment: And the span is definitely within the foreach?

Comment: Absolutely, they are inside the very same td, btw I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Works ok here.

```js
vm = {
    fee: ko.observableArray([{ fee: 1 }, { fee: 2 }])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: fee">
     <tr>
          <td>
              <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: fee, attr: {name : 'srv'+$index()}" data-val="true" data-val-number="error msg" data-val-regex="err msg" data-val-regex-pattern="\d+(\.\d{1,2})?" data-val-required="required"/>

              <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-bind="attr : { 'data-valmsg-for': 'srv'+$index()}" />
         </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```